# using beanshell postprocessor unable to write particuler text into a file,giving null?

Tags: csv, jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to write the data into csv file, i'm able to write some values into csv file but unable to write one value which is having more than 20 words in a sentence.

Text: `<msg>Congratulations! Your hall eGift Card of 120000 INR has been redeemed successfully on all Merchant Your redemption transaction number is 188</msg>`

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;


pramvalues=vars.get("paramvalues_2");

Result = "FAIL";
Response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

if(Response.contains("Congratulations! Your hall eGift Card"))
    Result = "PASS";


f = new FileOutputStream("E:/ApacheJmeter/TestResults/Results.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f);

p.println(vars.get("mes")+","+Result);

p.close();
f.close();
```

I'm getting "mes" as "null" but in debug, sampler data is coming.

Please provide help.

Comment: mes in debug sampler data found in SystemProperties/JMeterProperties or JMeterVariables?

Answer (score 0):

Writing lines into file using Beanshell isn't the best idea as if you will be doing this concurrently with many threads you will run into race conditions and your results file will be corrupt.

I would recommend the following:

1. Use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to check presence of `Congratulations! Your hall eGift Card` text in the response
2. Use [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property to "tell" JMeter to store `mes` variable value into .jtl results file. You can do it in 2 ways:

   - Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

     ```
     sample_variables=mes
     ```
   - or pass it via [-J command-line argument like](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

     ```
     jmeter -Jsample_variables=mes -n -t test.jmx -l resutl.jtl
     ```

     See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them

     Assuming everything goes well you should see an extra column called `mes` in your .jtl results file, it will contain `${mes}` variable value.

---

If you still want to use scripting switch to [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/), also it might be a good idea to use [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) to avoid race conditions.